# $f(x)$ is increasing, $g(x)$ is decreasing. Can we asses monotonicity of $f(x) + g(x)$, $f(g(x))$, etc by proving different speeds of changing?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, monotone-functions

Say, $f(x)$ is increasing and $g(x)$ is decreasing.

Based on (provable) different speed of increasing/decreasing, can we formulate rules like:

1. $f(x) + g(x)$ will be increasing/decreasing?
2. $f(x) - g(x)$ will be increasing/decreasing?
3. $f(g(x)) $ will be increasing/decreasing?
4. $f(x) * g(x)$ will be increasing/decreasing?

And how to prove such "different speed of increasing/decreasing"?

For example, can we somehow *use infinitesimals with a higher order of smallness / different orders of smallnes?*

Comment: $f(g(x))$ will always be decreasing unconditionally.

Comment: @M. Rumpy Am I right that if it is visa versa: $f(x)$ is decreasing, $g(x)$ is increasing =>$f(g(x))$ is also decreasing, because $f'(g) * g' < 0$ (because $f' < 0$ and $g' > 0$)?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose $f$ and $g$ are differentiable, then $f'\geq0$ and $g'\leq 0$.

By this assumption, we can only say surely that $f-g$ is increasing and $f\circ g$ is decreasing because
$$(f(x)-g(x))'=f'(x)-g'(x)\geq0$$
and $$f(g(x))'=f'(g(x))g'(x)\leq0.$$
For other cases we can show by examples that the functions $f+g$ and $fg$ may be non-monotonic.

Comment: That's good, but $f-g$ is increasing and $f\circ g$ is decreasing even if $f$ and $g$ are not differentiable. That follows easily from the definition.

Answer (score 1):

1. $f + g$ can be increasing or decreasing or neither (e.g. constant).
2. $f - g$ -increasing since $-g$ is increasing.
3. $f \circ g$ is decreasing : take $x \leqslant y$, then $g(y) \leqslant g(x)$ hence $f(g(y)) \leqslant f(g(x))$.
4. $f \cdot g$ can be increasing or decreasing or neither (e.g. constant).

   > And how to prove such "different speed of increasing/decreasing"?

The tool you are looking for is **differentiation**. If a function $f : \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, say with derivative $f'$, we can mesure how much the function $f$ increases/decreases on a certain interval $I$ :

- $f'(x) = 0$ for almost all $x \in I$ iff $f$ is constant on $I$.
- $f'(x) > 0$ for almost all $x \in I$ iff $f$ is strictly increasing on $I$.
- $f'(x) < 0$ for almost all $x \in I$ iff $f$ is strictly decreasing on $I$.

This gives you a criterion for question 1. : Assume $|f'(x)| > |g'(x)|$ for almost all $x \in I$, then $f + g$ is increasing on $I$ since $(f + g)' = f' + g'$ and $f'(x) + g'(x) > 0$.

But beware for question 4. ! In general, $(f\cdot g)' \neq f'\cdot g'$. Luckily, we have the Leibnitz formula : $\boxed{(f \cdot g)' = f' \cdot g + f \cdot g'}$

Comment: It is possible that $f+g$ is neither increasing, decreasing nor constant. Consider $f(x)=x+\sin(x)$ and $g(x)=-x+\cos(x)$ for example. The same is true for $fg$

Comment: @Taladris Indeed, I've been careless! It is fixed now. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

In general, only $f-g$ is sure to be increasing and $f\circ g$ is sure to be decreasing. Indeed, $f$ increasing means that

> for every $x_1$ and $x_2$ in the domain of $f$, if $x_1<x_2$, then $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$

Similarly, $g$ decreasing means that

> for every $x_1$ and $x_2$ in the domain of $g$, if $x_1<x_2$, then $g(x_1)>g(x_2)$.

---

**$f-g$ is increasing**

Assume that $x_1<x_2$ in the domain of $f-g$ (that is, the intersection of the domains of $f$ and $g$).

By definition, $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$ and $g(x_1)>g(x_2)$. The second inequality implies that $-g(x_1)<-g(x_2)$, so $(f-g)(x_1)<(f-g)(x_2)$.

By definition, $f-g$ is increasing.

---

**$f\circ g$ is decreasing**

Assume that $x_1<x_2$ in the domain of $f\circ g$.

By definition, $g(x_1)>g(x_2)$. Since $f$ is increasing, we have $f(g(x_1))>f(g(x_2))$, which means $f\circ g(x_1)>f\circ g(x_2)$.

By definition, $f\circ g$ is decreasing.

---

**Cases of $f+g$ and $fg$**

Consider $f(x)=mx$ and $g(x)=nx$ with $m>0$ (so that $f$ is increasing) and $n<0$ (so that $g$ is decreasing).

Then $(f+g)(x)=(m+n)x$ and $f+g$ can be increasing, decreasing or constant depending on the choice of the values of $m$ and $n$.

Also, $fg(x)=mnx^2$ is quadratic, so not increasing and not decreasing.